# How to delete in one time few buttons or text fields?

Tags: java, swing

This code is taking to much place. Can I group it together?

```
panel.remove(text);
panel.remove(text1);
panel.remove(text2);
```

Something like this:

```
panel.remove(text)(text1)(text2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try [`removeAll()`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs368-2/JavaTutorial/jdk1.2/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll%28%29) (inherited from the Container class) which removes all components from the container.

```
panel.removeAll()
```

Comment: I cant' remove everything, only few staff.

Comment: looks like your only two choices are `remove` (one at a time) and `removeAll` (removing all components).  [JPanel docs](http://edelstein.pebbles.cs.cmu.edu/jadeite/main.php?api=java6&state=class&package=java.awt&class=Container#remove%28int%29) -- maybe you want to loop through your components (removing one at a time in each iteration)...?